# QuickFix C++ - How to established Trading session from client APP?

Tags: c++, qtquick2, quickfix

I have build my quickfix C++ source code with the SSL support using below command. My quickfix library got build successfully.

On Linux (with system openssl),

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DHAVE_SSL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="install-path" .. make -j 4 install
```

This is my Initiator code -

```
if (isSSL.compare("SSL") == 0)
    initiator = new FIX::ThreadedSSLSocketInitiator ( application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory );
else
    initiator = new FIX::SocketInitiator( application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory );
```

But while running this getting linking issue. What is the problem ?

```
CMakeFiles/TradingClient.dir/tradeclient.cpp.o: In function `main':
/mnt/d/TradingClient/tradeclient.cpp:47: undefined reference to `FIX::ThreadedSSLSocketInitiator::ThreadedSSLSocketInitiator(FIX::Application&, FIX::MessageStoreFactory&, FIX::SessionSettings const&, FIX::LogFactory&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(TradingClient)

add_definitions(-DHAVE_SSL=1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(quickfix_lib "/usr/lib/libquickfix.so")

add_executable(TradingClient Application.h Application.cpp tradeclient.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TradingClient ${quickfix_lib} )
```

if you go inside quickfix/src/C++/CMakeLists.txt

```
 if (HAVE_SSL)
  set (quickfix_SOURCES ${quickfix_SOURCES}
    SSLSocketAcceptor.cpp
    SSLSocketConnection.cpp
    SSLSocketInitiator.cpp
    ThreadedSSLSocketAcceptor.cpp
    ThreadedSSLSocketConnection.cpp
    ThreadedSSLSocketInitiator.cpp
    UtilitySSL.cpp)
endif()
```

these files get build only with SSL . It means my quickfix library is correctly build because object files for these files got generated.

Although object files gets generated as part of library, still getting this linking issue that its not able to find the reference for these methods   ThreadedSSLSocketInitiator()

Comment: And `CMakeLists.txt` of your project?

Comment: @pptaszni added the CMakeLists.txt. I have added some more observations. please go through. I am beginner in FIX. Please help me out

Comment: This is not related to the quickfix library. Your CMakeLists syntax is wrong. Study more on that.(Use find_library().)

Comment: `set(quickfix_lib "/usr/lib/libquickfix.so")` this doesn't make any sense. If you are sure `libquickfix` is installed in your system correctly, it is enough to just use `target_link_libraries(TradingClient quickfix)`. And your `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="install-path"` also doesn't make sense. If you want it in the default system location, don't use this argument.

Comment: Clear your system and try to install this lib without unnecessary parameters: `cd build`, `cmake -DHAVE_SSL=ON ../`, `make -j`, and then `sudo make install`. You can verify with `sudo ldconfig -v` that your system see this library correctly installed.

Comment: but this is not related to compilation issue . Its quickfix source code bug. I found one blog related to that

this file has missing  entry -- #cmakedefine HAVE_SSL 1, I have added in this file
cat cmake_config.h.in
#ifndef CONFIG_H_IN
#define CONFIG_H_IN
#cmakedefine HAVE_EMX
#cmakedefine HAVE_CXX17
#cmakedefine HAVE_STD_SHARED_PTR
#cmakedefine HAVE_SHARED_PTR_IN_TR1_NAMESPACE
#cmakedefine HAVE_STD_TR1_SHARED_PTR_FROM_TR1_MEMORY_HEADER
#cmakedefine HAVE_STD_UNIQUE_PTR
#cmakedefine HAVE_SSL 1
#endif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but this is not related to compilation issue .Its quickfix source code bug.
I found one blog related to that this file has missing entry

```
#cmakedefine HAVE_SSL 1
```

I have added in this file

`cat cmake_config.h.in`

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H_IN 
#define CONFIG_H_IN 

#cmakedefine HAVE_EMX 
#cmakedefine HAVE_CXX17 
#cmakedefine HAVE_STD_SHARED_PTR 
#cmakedefine HAVE_SHARED_PTR_IN_TR1_NAMESPACE 
#cmakedefine HAVE_STD_TR1_SHARED_PTR_FROM_TR1_MEMORY_HEADER 
#cmakedefine HAVE_STD_UNIQUE_PTR 
#cmakedefine HAVE_SSL 1
#endif
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No it's not a quick fix bug, but the OP's fault on his build system.